# Using Enum as a int value

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

Am trying to use Enum as Constants for readability as below .

```
Public enum x { test1 , test2 , test3 }
```

I want to pass this enum into a method and use it as a int value as shown

```
private void (int type)
{ 
  switch(int) 
  {
    case enum.X:
          // do somthing 
           break;
   }
 } ;
```

Can we use enum here as its more clearer than using a int value .( like switch 1 etc) . Is it possible to use this way.?

Comment: enum.X doesn't mean anything. Enums are just ints that are abstracted away, though. test1 = 0, test2=1, and test3=2. You can use enums and their integer representations interchangeably.

Comment: That's true in C#, but not in Java!

Comment: No they're not. They're classes whose instances have an associated int (the enum's ordinal). You can define methods on them, create not-default constructors, etc.

Comment: I'm confused now. Why do you need an int? Anyway if you have one cast it to the enum, then use that in the switch

Comment: If you need an int, use an int, not an enum. This is not C and they are not interchangeable and do not work the same way. Java enums are actually classes, not primitives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use an enum in a `switch` statement in Java:

```
public enum SomeEnum { FOO, BAR, BAZ };

// in a class...
private void something(SomeEnum s) {
    switch (s) {
        case FOO:
            // do something
            break;
        case BAR:
            // do something else
            break;
    }
}
```

Not sure I understand how int values tie into this, but you can have fields/methods on an enum like in a normal Java class, and can use these to hold int (or any other type) values as on any other POJO.

Here's an example in which we declare a constructor for an enum class, so that you can pass in values for internal variables at the time each instance of the enum is constructed.  To help you follow what's going on: First we declare the items in the enum - each declaration invokes the constructor, so we can pass in instance variables here.  Then the code for the enum class follows, as with a normal Java class.

```
public enum AnotherEnum {
    ONE(1, "un"), TWO(2, "deux"), THREE(3, "trois"), FIFTY_SEVEN(57, "cinquante-sept");

    private final int someInt;
    private final String french;
    private AnotherEnum(int i, String s) {
        this.someInt = i;
        this.french = s;
    }
    public int getSomeInt() {
        return this.someInt;
    }
    public String getFrench() {
        return this.french;
    }
}
```

So for example, `System.out.println(AnotherEnum.TWO.getSomeInt())` would print `2`, and `System.out.println(AnotherEnum.FIFTY_SEVEN.getFrench())` would print `cinquante-sept`.

Comment: Oh Nice I can use the above said way . But how does it work how is getSomeInt for Two returning 2 . I am using enum for the very first time so wanted know more on this

Comment: Not sure I understand your "how does it work" question, so I've expanded the example to hopefully make what's going on more clear.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot say:

```
case Enumerator.ordinal():
```

But you could say:

```
switch(EnumObject.values()[intVar]) {
  case Enumerator1:
       ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do this by doing a little more work with you enum class.

```
public enum Foo {
   X (1),
   Y (2);

   private int value;

   Foo (int value)
   {
        this.value = value;
   }
}
```

Now all you need to do is:

```
    switch (int)
    {
        case Foo.X: doSomething ();break;
        case Foo.Y: doSomething ();break;
    }
```

Comment: This won't compile - the expression in a `case` statement must be a constant, and so cannot not the result of a method call.